# How to get the number of hours with "no observations" for every six hours for each variable in a dataframe

Tags: r, statistics

**I'm new to R and I can't find the right way to do this.**
I have this **data frame**
It's for my university project.

basically, I need to **find the number of hours with "no observations"** (I'm guessing this means the number of NA's) **for the intervals of 6 hours** (for example (0h...6h/6h,12h) and **the mediums of these intervals**
I have to then **group these intervals into another data frame** where the **variable**s are the mediums I I previously calculated and **the rows** are the intervals of 6 hours

I tried to maybe cut the data frame by intervals of 6 like this (this doesnt seem to work):

```
b<-as.data.frame(Air[1:6,1:13])
b

  typeof(b)
  typeof(Air)
  typeof(u)
u<-as.data.frame.array((summary(b)))
u
```

Comment: Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and note in particular that code needs to be complete and reproducible including all inputs where inputs are shown using dput(X) where X is the input.  As it stands no one but you can run the code in the question.

Comment: Hi rorolulu, welcome to SO! Tip: The quality of any possible answer is greatly increased if you provide a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example.